# how to use += operator to add characters to a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I have this Char.h file:

```
struct Node {
    char value;
    Node* next;
};

class CharList {
private:
    Node* head_;  //point to the first Node of the list
    Node* tail_;  //point to the last Node of the list
    unsigned size_; //the number of Nodes in the list
public:
    CharList();
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const CharList&);
    CharList& operator+=(char c);
};
```

And I need to implement the `+=` operator, but I am really struggling and I don't know how to do it.

This is what I have so far:

```
CharList& CharList::operator+=(char c) {
    
    Node* ptr = new Node;
    ptr->value = c;
    ptr->next = nullptr;
    this->head_ +=c;

    return *this;
}
```

On the `main()` function, I want it to be able to run so that the results look something like this:

```
+='M' M
+='C' M->C
+='S' M->C->S
```

Comment: `this->head_ +=c;` Why are you adding a `char` to a pointer?

Answer (score 2):

You are close, you are just not linking the newly created `Node` to the rest of the list correctly.  Try this instead:

```cpp
CharList& CharList::operator+=(char c) {
    
    Node* ptr = new Node;
    ptr->value = c;
    ptr->next = nullptr;

    if (!head_) head_ = ptr;
    if (tail_) tail_->next = ptr;
    tail_ = ptr;
    ++size_;

    return *this;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/9987d0)

Don't forget to add a destructor, a copy/move constructor, and a copy/move-assignment operator to `CharList`, per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @TedLyngmo It can, yes. I just prefer to be more explicit about it